# ruby split using regex -- but keep the matched texted in the result

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have the following string:

```
705 veliký big, great, large 707 čistý clear, clean 710 vnitřní inner, internal
```

And I want to insert line feeds before each number and still *retain* the number.  Like so:

```
705 veliký big, great, large
707 čistý clear, clean 
710 vnitřní inner, internal
```

Everything I have found on `String.split(/regex/)` always throws away the pattern matched.  But in this instance, I want to keep it.

I'm happy to do this either in Ruby or in Textmate, but I have the same problem on each. The matched pattern is replaced with the carriage return.

Comment: Are you after just [`my_string.gsub(/\d+/, "\r\\0")`](https://ideone.com/jsFiaa)? I do not understand why you speak about *splitting* while you say *I want to insert line feeds before each number and still retain the number.* **What should be the final output?**

Comment: What do you mean retain the pattern matched? What is the problem with something like `s.gsub(/ (?=\d)/, "\n")`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question please take the time to format your question so it's readable and follows the normal SO look. The effort you put into a question pays off. Please read http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the content of a split-regex with braces like this:

```
s = '705 veliký big, great, large 707 čistý clear, clean 710 vnitřní inner, internal'
puts s.split(/(\d+)/)
```

The (wrong) result will be:

```
705
 veliký big, great, large 
707
 cistý clear, clean 
710
 vnitrní inner, internal
```

The split is done before and after each number.

So I would recommend to make first a `gsub`:

```
puts s.gsub(/(\d+)/, "\n\\1")
```

**Attention!**
The result of the `gsub` is again a string (with line feeds), `split` returns an array (without line feeds)! The linefeeds in my result code is made by the `puts` command.

Comment: This was what I needed.  You are right, gsub was a better tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for here is [positive lookahead](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors):

```
"705 veliký large 707 čistý, clean 710 vnitřní internal".split(/ (?=\d)/)
#⇒ ["705 veliký large", "707 čistý, clean", "710 vnitřní internal"]
```

To get the string with carriage returns, just `join("\n")` the result above.

Comment: Looks about right but I'm not sure what the `+` is for

Comment: @pguardiario Indeed, it makes no sense here. Thx, updated.

Comment: mudasobwa --- you are right.  the positive lookahead was what I needed.  thx.